# Determining convergence of series which seems to be oscillating

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find, whether the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}nx\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{\sin^2(k\alpha)}{1 + x^2 + \cos^2(k\alpha)}.$$
I'm trying to find it using the ratio test. In order to determine convergence of series I need to evaluate limit
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{\sin^2(\alpha +\alpha n)}{1 + x^2 + \cos^2(\alpha + \alpha n)}$$
and I've tried to use identities, expansions and so, but I can't find the way. Where to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your original question?

Comment: That limit does not converge.

Comment: This seems to have oscillatory value (i.e. limit doesn't exist), can you post original problem?

Comment: "whether the series ..." that needs completing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal in applying the ratio test is to prove that $|a_{n+1}/a_n|\le k<1$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and some fixed $k$.  (Baby Rudin 3.34.)  You don't need for $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ to converge.  Oscillation is fine so long as it's oscillation in an interval $[0,k]$ with $k<1$.

In this case, for large $n$ we have $(n+1)/n$ arbitrarily close to $1$, while 
$$\frac{\sin^2(\alpha +\alpha n)}{1 + x^2 + \cos^2(\alpha+\alpha n)}\le {1\over 1+x^2}$$
The ratio test is therefore met for $n$ so large that ${n+1\over n}\cdot {1\over 1+x^2}<1$. This will happen for sufficiently large $n$ whenever $x\ne 0$.

Comment: You might consider stating that all we need is $\limsup_{n+1}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$ to assure convergence.  You've tacitly shown this, but you might just consider explicitly stating it.  (+1) for the answer.  -Mark